SwiftData @Query crash when filter parameter is not nil?
I want use dynamically change the Predicate, so that different list can display different data. However, when I click the 'NavigationLink' to get in the ReminderListView() then the app will get stuck, no responding,

struct ReminderListView: View {
    // ...
    @Query private var reminderList: [Reminder]

    init(filter: ReminderPredicate) {
        let sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor<Reminder>]
        let filterPredicate: Predicate<Reminder>
        
        switch filter {
        case .filterAllReminder:
            filterPredicate = #Predicate<Reminder> { $0.createDate != nil }
            sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\Reminder.completeDate, order: .forward)]
        case .filterFinishedReminder:
            filterPredicate = #Predicate<Reminder> { $0.completeDate != nil}
            sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\Reminder.completeDate, order: .forward)]
        }
        
        _reminderList = Query(filter: filterPredicate, sort: sortDescriptors)
    }
 // ...
}

ReminderPredicate is an enum.
If I change filter to nil of Query(),  then it works: _reminderList = Query(filter: nil, sort: sortDescriptors)
I also tried pass predicate directly which doesn't work: _reminderList = Query(filter: #Predicate<Reminder> { $0.createDate != nil }, sort: sortDescriptors)

Please read https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-filter-swiftdata-results-with-predicates. It is all too easy to construct a predicate that SwiftData can't handle, even though it compiles, and it looks like that might be what is happening to you.

Maybe it would help if you included the model definition.

I find a solution from apple dev forum, and share it here so that can help some one have same problem.

It seems if a NavigationStack is placed in the parent view of a child view with a @Query with predicate, the child view will get invalidated when navigating to or back from the destination view. The simplest is adding a dummy intermediate View between the View with the NavigationStack and the one with the @Query with predicate like this below: from apple dev forum

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            DummyView()
        }
    }
}

struct DummyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ListsView()
    }
}

struct ListsView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Item> { _ in true }) 

// ...
}


